# How to make sense of 'great weekend listens'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, american-english

How can I make sense of:

> great weekend listens

What is the definition of 'listens' in this context? What its grammatical class?

Comment: It is almost impossible to say without more context.  Can you tell us more about where you found it?

Comment: I assume it is being used as a noun with the sense 'things to listen to'.

Comment: It's like: good eats

Comment: What @KateBunting said - ***listen*** is a *"**nounified verb**"* coinage in such contexts. Same as, but less common than *Let me look! I want **a look**!*

Answer (score 2):

While more context would be helpful and should be provided for a SE question, I think it  highly likely that "listens" here means "things to listen to, quite likely radio or other audio broadcasts, although it could also mean recordings. Thus "good weekend listens" would mean things interesting, enjoyable or profitable to listen to on a weekend. The phrase is a parallel with the more common "good summer reads", meaning books suitable for reading during the summer, particularly while on vacation.